# Any solutions for transferring media between Mobile Clients

Tags: server

Please bear with me as I am a complete beginner at this but looking to learn.

I am looking for a service or any advice in a solution to transfer media from Mobile to Mobile.

Say I want to send a picture from my cell phone to yours through a server, when that picture is received the data does not persist on the server.

Is there any server that accomplishes this or are is there a server setup/configuration that exists to do this?

Thank you so much and my apologies if this is the wrong place to post this. Between Stack Overflow, Serverfault and this site. I had no idea which one was the proper place for such a generic question.

Comment: This belongs on Web Apps or Superuser. Pro Webmasters is for questions related to webmasters (people who build/operate/maintain websites). In any case, you can use email or SMS to send moderate-sized files from one mobile device to another. This option is readily available through any cellular or email provider.